# how to write punjabi language text in our application of android?

Tags: android, text

hi
    I am going to start an application in android. But i want the text should be written in Punjabi language in the Text view but while i am copying the Punjabi text and paste it into text view(widget) it will display nothing on the Emulator. So, please give me any suggestion so that i am able to write Punjabi language in the text view of android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Typeface fontStyle = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "bulara_5.ttf");  
text.setTypeface(fontStyle);  
text.setText("ਪੰਜਾਬੀ");
```